# Data interpolation

Tags: google-earth-engine

Any idea how to do time series data interpolation in Google Earth Engine? I used the code below but I do not get results. I keep getting computation timeout.

```
//DATA INTERPOLATION
// Sample the Sndvi image at 1000 random locations.
var samples = Sndvi.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
  .sample({region:G , scale:10, numPixels: 1000})
  .map(function(sample) {
    var lat = sample.get('latitude');
    var lon = sample.get('longitude');
    var NDVI = sample.get('NDVI');
    return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([lon, lat]), {Sndvi: NDVI})
        .copyProperties(composite, ["system:time_start"])
     });
 // print(samples)

// Interpolate Sndvi from the sampled points.
var interpolated = samples.kriging({
  propertyName: 'Sndvi',
  shape: 'exponential',
  range: 100 * 1000,
  sill: 1.0,
  nugget: 0.1,
  maxDistance: 100 * 1000,
  reducer: 'mean',
});
```

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question. Your code suggests that you are doing spatial interpolation, but your question suggests time series interpolation. Additionally, please provide a complete working script. Share any assets used or mock up a simplified script that replicates the issue.

Comment: Hello Justin, please attached is a link to my code. I am doing NDVI time series over a span of 3 years. I do not have enough scenes for the time series, hence that is why I was considering data interpolation.
 https://code.earthengine.google.com/6107387e49d1646d3b68332d5e9a578a